# Information that can be extracted from the time-ordered correlation function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

The time-ordered correlation function can be very complicated and encodes a tremendous amount of information. For example, the LSZ formula can be used to extract S-matrix elements from the time-ordered correlation function. What other quantities in the context of quantum field theory can be extracted from the time-ordered correlation function?

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, **all** the information of the QFT is encoded in the $n$-point functions. This means that, once you know the correlation functions, you know the Hilbert space, the fields and their algebra (modulo a  unitary transformation). This is known as the *Wightman reconstruction theorem*, though AFAIK, it is not known whether the theorem holds for Yang-Mills theories (the Standard Model) or not: it is an open problem.

The details of the theorem are quite involved (and I'm not familiar with them, nor with AQFT in general), but if you want to read about Wightman's QFT [this scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Wightman_quantum_field_theory) seems nice.

Now I'll try to be more specific: in practice, what do we know once we know the $n$-point functions? The first thing, as you already noted, is that the $n$-point functions give us the information of all scattering phenomena. But apart from this, the $n$-point functions carry the information of the possible decays (and their time constants); the  poles of the correlators give you the energy of bound states (e.g., you can use this to calculate the mass of the proton using the QCD Lagrangian); the correlators are easily related to effective vertices (which contain the information of the electric and magnetic moments, for example); etc.